# Le « pouding-chômeur » : origine et lexicalisation ?

Tags: prépositions, québec, origine-ou-raison, alimentation, trait-d-union

Dans le [*Grand dictionnaire terminologique*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=17563893) on a l'orthographe [rectifiée](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4725) ainsi que le trait d'union pour cet « entremets composé d'une pâte à gâteau qu'on dépose sur un sirop fait de cassonade, d'eau et de beurre, et qu'on fait cuire au four » c'est-à-dire le *pouding-chômeur* ou *pouding du chômeur* (n.m., voir aussi une variante sans trait d'union sur [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pouding-ch%C3%B4meur_(dessert))), « du fait qu'il était économique à la fabrication » nous dit-on (GDT). [Aux É.-U.](https://www.nytimes.com/1986/07/20/travel/savoring-summer-en-plein-air.html) et ailleurs on a certainement déjà entendu parler du mets, peut-être moins que de la [*poutine*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8361736) ou du [*pâté chinois*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8873150). D'[autres](https://www.ledevoir.com/vivre/alimentation/168688/un-p-tit-dessert-mais-pas-d-entree) parlent de *pouding au chômeur*. Selon « la légende », le dessert aurait été inventé « au cours de la crise économique des années 30 » et serait l'oeuvre de « Georgette Falardeau, femme de Camilien Houde, maire de Montréal » ou pourrait aussi avoir été inspiré d'un dessert populaire en Nouvelle-France, les  «cachettes» aux petits fruits (Le Devoir, *Un p'tit dessert... mais pas d'entrée*, Fabien Deglise, 15 décembre 2007).

---

- A-t-on autre chose qu'une légende à se mettre sous la dent en ce qui
  a trait à l'origine du nom de ce dessert ; quand et où le nom
  apparaît-il d'abord ; à l'origine était-ce employé avec une préposition et le cas échéant est-ce *du* ou *au* ; l'une ou l'autre préposition est-elle davantage en phase avec la sémantique ou l'origine du terme, est-ce une référence aux ingrédients ou au public à qui le dessert aurait été destiné ?
- Le trait d'union participe souvent d'une dynamique de lexicalisation
  des noms : peut-on expliquer pourquoi *pouding-chômeur* a un trait
  d'union au GDT alors que *pâté chinois* n'en a pas ?
- Ailleurs qu'au Québec, compte tenu des informations disponibles, l'associerait-t-on davantage à la sémantique protéiforme du [*pudding*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/pudding/64986?q=pudding#64254), à celle du [*gâteau*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/g%C3%A2teau) ou à un autre terme de pâtisserie ; comprend-on différement le [*pouding* du *pudding*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pudding%2Cpouding&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpudding%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpouding%3B%2Cc0) ; connaît-on le terme *pouding-chômeur* aussi bien que le terme *poutine* ?

Comment: Ton explication de l'origine me semble complète, je n'ai jamais entendu autre chose.  Par contre, je n'ai jamais entendu "au chômeur" (on dirait qu'on mange une partie d'un chômeur!), ou "du chômeur".  J'ai toujours entendu l'expression sans préposition.  Dans la population francophone *pouding chômeur* est très connu, mais *poutine* est bien plus connu dans la majorité des autres communautés et en dehors du Québec.

Comment: @Nic3500 Merci, j'en ai mangé et j'en ai cuisiné sans jamais me demander d'où le nom venait etc. Mon explication vient de l'article du Devoir mais me semble qui si ça venait de l'épouse d'un maire, on aurait ça dans une biographie sans doute ? Mon exp. perso. c'est que je dis le nom sans préposition, et à l'écrit je n'aurais pas eu le réflexe d'utiliser la graphie rectifiée, que j'aime bien par ailleurs, et je n'aurais pas mis le trait d'union. Je n'ai jamais entendu _du chômeur_ mais je connais _au chômeur_, plus ancien, p.-ê. plus régional...

Comment: @Nic3500 _Au chômeur_, ce serait p.-ê. comme _cachette aux fruits_ où on substitue fruits pour une métonymie de celui dont les ingrédients sont moins riches. Ou ce pourrait être le mets _offert/servant au_ chômeur, au lieu d'être celui _du chômeur_, lui appartenant, lui étant associé. Est-ce que le trait d'union serait un signe de lexicalisation ou un signe de réduction de la préposition ici ? N'hésite pas à verser ton commentaire en réponse même si c'était partiel. Merci !

Comment: Dans ma famille, "au chômeur" va provoquer des rires et des farces, car chômeur est immédiatement lié aux travailleurs sans emplois.  Quant-à l'utilisation du trait d'union, je n'ai jamais fait de recherches pour voir si c'est correct ou pas.  À l'usage je ne l'ai jamais vu avec.

Comment: Merci pour cette découverte culinaire que je ne manquerai pas d'essayer !

Answer (score 1):

Bonjour, voici une combinaison de mes 2 commentaires.

Ton explication de l'origine me semble complète, je n'ai jamais entendu autre chose.  Ne pas oublier que le tout est "selon la légende", et je doute fortement que ce dessert n'existait pas avant les années 30.  Mais c'est une opinion, pas un fait de ma part.

Par contre, je n'ai jamais entendu "au chômeur" (on dirait qu'on mange une partie d'un chômeur!), ou "du chômeur". J'ai toujours entendu l'expression sans préposition.  Dans ma famille, l'utilisation de "au chômeur" va provoquer des rires et des farces, car chômeur est immédiatement lié aux travailleurs sans emploi.

Dans la population francophone pouding chômeur est très connu, mais poutine est bien plus connu dans la majorité des autres communautés et en dehors du Québec.

Quant-à l'utilisation du trait d'union, je n'ai jamais fait de recherches pour voir si c'est correct ou pas. À l'usage je ne l'ai jamais vu avec.